# Vlookup Search Issue using *

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a problem with the Vlookup function and I can not think of a way to fix it. For certain reasons, I could not add columns so I would have to be able to solve it in the formula.

Basically, I have two strings in the same column, CEP * and CEPCP and on the right I have other columns with information belonging to those two strings. The problem is that if I do a Vlookup from another sheet, when I search for the string CEP * it brings me the CEPCP information because excel interprets that I'm looking for anything that starts with CEP.

Is there any way to solve it with formulas?

Thanks!

EDIT: The Vlookup is the following:

`VLOOKUP(A2;Users!A:P;4;FALSE)`

Being A2 the CEP *

Comment: lookup `CEP~*` which will force the lookup of the literal `*`

Comment: @ScottCraner I see, but if my Vlookup is the following `VLOOKUP(A2;Usuarios!A:P;4;FALSE)` Being A2 the CEP *, how do I include the ~?

Comment: Please add that information in the post, so others do not need to weed through the comments to find that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append the `*` with `~*` to let Excel know that you want the actual string not the wildcard.

```
SUBSTITUTE(A2;"*";"~*")
```

SUBSTITUTE does not use wildcards.

```
VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"*";"~*");Users!A:P;4;FALSE)
```